# Difficulties fitting a Cox PH model with categorical interactions to complex survey data

Tags: r, categorical-data, interaction, survey, cox-model

I'm attempting to fit a Cox proportional hazards model to a set of NHANES data; the code to load and clean the data is [here](https://github.com/dhicks/obesity/blob/mwe/load%20data.R), and the resulting dataset is [here](https://github.com/dhicks/obesity/blob/mwe/2016-05-24.Rdata?raw=true).

The difficulty I'm having is illustrated by the following [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhicks/obesity/mwe/mwe.R):

```
library(dplyr)
library(survey)
library(survival)

datafile = '2016-05-24.Rdata'
if (!file.exists(datafile)) {
    download.file('https://github.com/dhicks/obesity/blob/mwe/2016-05-24.Rdata?raw=true',
                  datafile)
}
load(datafile)

df = df[complete.cases(df),]

## ----------
## W/o sampling weights
df.working = df %>% filter(!smoker, age.months >= 50*12, age.months < 85*12)
coxfit.unweighted = coxph(Surv(age.months, mort.status == 'deceased') ~ 
                            bmi.cat * bmi.max.cat,
                   data = df.working)
summary(coxfit.unweighted)


## ----------
## W/ sampling weights
## cf the svydesign call in the docs for survey::nhanes
design = svydesign(id = ~ psu, strata = ~ stratum, weights = ~ sample.weight, 
                   nest = TRUE, 
                   data = {df %>% filter(!smoker, age.months >= 50*12, age.months < 85*12)})
coxfit.weighted = svycoxph(Surv(age.months, mort.status == 'deceased') ~ 
                            bmi.cat * bmi.max.cat, 
                 design = design)
```

The variable `bmi.cat` is a factor variable for body mass index categories (underweight, normal weight, overweight, etc.).  The variable `bmi.max.cat` is a factor variable for the same categories for the respondent's maximum recalled weight.  Since `bmi.cat` is necessarily less than or equal to `bmi.max.cat`, there are lots of empty cells in the crosstab of these two variables.

The chunk of code fitting `coxfit.unweighted` using `survival::coxph` raises a warning about singularities (because of all the empty cells), but does fit a model.  It's unweighted, and so I need to use `survey::svycoxph` to get unbiased estimates.  But the call fitting `coxfit.weighted` returns

```
Error in solve.default(g$var, coef(g)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[9,9] = 0
```

*Background*: I'm working towards replicating the analysis in [this paper, table 3](http://pophealthmetrics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1478-7954-12-6).  I've omitted the other covariates from the MWE for the sake of simplicity.  I have no previous experience with either survival analysis or analyzing data from complex surveys like NHANES, so radical course corrections to my analysis approach would be fine.

Comment: hi, it might be easier for others to help you troubleshoot if you include the download in your reproducible example so we can work with the same `df` object as you.  examples of download automation here https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/master/National%20Health%20and%20Nutrition%20Examination%20Survey

Comment: Okay, there you go

Comment: yo, not sure if your creation of the design aligns with cdc estimates, you should review the replication scripts before you go further..  dplyr+survey together often create bugs, try to avoid unless you're using the srvyr package.  naming an object `df` conflicts with the function, always avoid that.thanks

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized there was a conflict with `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `interaction` function with `drop = TRUE` to remove the empty levels of the interaction term.  Here's how it looks in context:

```
## W/ sampling weights
## cf the svydesign call in the docs for survey::nhanes
dataf$bmi.cat.inter = interaction(dataf$bmi.cat, dataf$bmi.max.cat, drop = TRUE)
design = svydesign(id = ~ psu, strata = ~ stratum, weights = ~ sample.weight, 
                   nest = TRUE, 
                   data = {dataf %>% filter(!smoker, age.months >= 50*12, age.months < 85*12)})
coxfit.weighted = svycoxph(Surv(age.months, mort.status == 'deceased') ~ 
                            bmi.cat.inter, 
                 design = design)
summary(coxfit.weighted)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but there is a flaw both in the code and the solution that one should be aware of. When you define

```
design = svydesign(id = ~ psu, strata = ~ stratum, weights = ~ sample.weight, 
               nest = TRUE, 
               data = {df %>% filter(!smoker, age.months >= 50*12, age.months < 85*12)})
```

you are getting rid of all the population you filter out when defining the `data=` argument. CDC suggests always to define the design by including the whole dataset and then using subset from the survey package like:

```
design <- svydesign(id = ~ psu, strata = ~ stratum, weights = ~ sample.weight, 
               nest = TRUE, 
               data = df)

bmi_design <- subset(design,  all(!smoker, age.months >= 50*12, age.months < 85*12)))
```

Comment: There's a longer description of the issue here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411026/why-it-is-important-to-make-survey-design-object-svydesign-function-in-r-with-i/414900#414900

Answer (score 0):

is it caused by the zeroes in this table?  not sure if those will ever converge?

```
table( x$bmi.cat , x$bmi.max.cat )
```

if you use fake data

```
x$bmi.max.cat <- sample(1:5,nrow(x),replace=T)

design <- svydesign( ~ psu , strat= ~ stratum , weights = ~ sample.weight , nest = TRUE , data = subset( x , sample.weight > 0 ) )
w <- subset( design , !smoker & age.months >= 50*12 & age.months < 85*12 )
svycoxph(Surv(age.months, mort.status == 'deceased') ~ bmi.cat * bmi.max.cat, design = w)
```

Comment: The study I'm trying to reproduce estimated proportional hazards at each combination of `bmi.cat` and `bmi.max.cat`.  This `svycoxph` specification doesn't do that.  Without coercing the factors to numerics, the same error still appears.

Comment: you're right, sorry, i'm not sure of the answer.  i don't think those zero cells will ever work (but could be wrong)