# Why it is important to make survey design object (svydesign function in R with id, strata, weights, fpc) from raw data and after clean data in object?

Tags: r, survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights

I am planning to analyse a survey. I have been told that if I clean the data (e.g. data subsetting, value recoding, creating new variables from existing etc.) and afterwards create a survey design object ([svydesign function in "survey" package of R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/3.36/topics/svydesign) with id, strata, weights, fpc), I may get not correct point estimates and CI. I have been advised to make the survey design object first and then clean the data in that object. Can you please explain to me why this is necessary?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are doing to 'clean' the data? Could you demonstrate with some code/outputs to show the difference between cleaning before and afterwards?

Comment: @Izy I have not started cleaning data yet. I am planning to work with NHANES data. I looked at some tutorials about survey package (like this: http://asdfree.com/national-health-and-nutrition-examination-survey-nhanes.html) and they where first making survey design object and after data manipulation. Based on that I asked question to one person and have received brief answer (we had not have many time) that as general rule it is better to first create design object and after any data manipulation should be done on that object in order to get correct calculations. My question is why it is true?

Comment: @Izy By cleaning data I mean taking subset of observations that I need, some value recoding, creating new variables from existing and etc.

Comment: I haven't used the survey package, but I suspect that if a difference exists it may be because the package is doing something to use information about the overall population/sample (e.g. the variance), whereas subsetting beforehand and just analysing the subset would discard the other data. Have you searched for any information in the package documentation to explain what it is doing? - if so please detail what you found (or where you looked and didn't find anything)? Try it both ways round with some dummy data and see what happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

Sometimes, including with NHANES data, you **do** need to subset before defining the survey design object, because not all the records in the data set are part of the sample you are analysing.  In NHANES, everyone in the data file will have a health questionnaire, but only a subset will have a clinical examination, and there may be smaller subsets with specific biochemical measurements.  You need to remove records from the file that are not part of the sample you are analysing.

For example, I might use something like

```
nhanesmec <- subset(nhanes, !is.na(WTMEC2YR))
```

to analyse data from the clinical examination. Records with missing `WTMEC2YR` are not part of the MEC sample and so should not go into the survey design object.

On the other hand, if you have observations that **are part of the sample**, you should not remove them even if they have missing or implausible data, and you should not, eg, remove records for men if you want to do analyses only for women.

The reason is complicated, and makes almost no difference for NHANES.  However, you asked.

Let's ignore stratified sampling for now and just consider cluster sampling.  The survey was designed to sample a specific, preplanned number of clusters. When we're thinking about how different the results could be with a hypothetical replication of the survey [the frequentist definition of sampling uncertainty] we want to think about hypothetical replications that have the same preplanned number of clusters.

If you subset the data and end up removing one of the clusters, you no longer have the preplanned number of clusters. The number of clusters is now random, and you'd need to model the resulting variability due to number of clusters.

The computations to get the correct variances are equivalent to setting the weight to zero when you want to omit an observation, rather than just omitting it; we keep the number of clusters the same.  If you look at the output of `summary` on a subsetted survey design object you can see the object keeps track of how many clusters (PSUs) it has data for (which is random), and also how many it started with (which is fixed).  Using Anthony's example

```
library(survey)

data(api)

dstrat_after<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
dstrat_after <- subset( dstrat_after , comp.imp == 'Yes' )
summary(dstrat_after)
```

you will see as part of the output

```
Stratum Sizes: 
             E  H  M
obs         75 17 24
design.PSU 100 50 50
actual.PSU  75 17 24
```

If you subset before setting up the survey design object, there's no way for the object to know the planned number of observations or clusters, so there's no way for it to get the right standard errors.

And finally: this only makes a difference when your subset has fewer primary sampling units than the full sample.  In Anthony's example the PSUs are individual records, so the subset does have fewer. In NHANES the PSUs are cities or counties, so you'd have to remove **a lot** of observations before you lost a PSU. Also, since the design has only two PSUs per stratum, if you did lose a PSU you'd have other problems with estimating standard errors and would have to look up `survey.lonely.psu`.

So, for NHANES it's unlikely to actually matter.

Comment: Dear Prof Lumley, I have a question regarding subsetting survey design (stratified random sample) by the dependent variable (three categories), so as to conduct pairwise logistic regression models (question post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629001/is-it-reasonable-to-subset-a-survey-design-object-by-dependent-outcome-variabl). I know from your book that subsetting survey design object can be done for domain estimation that are not strata, I would like to ask if this is reasonable to do so. Any comments or thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

subsetting before creating the survey design will give you incorrect standard errors:

```
library(survey)

data(api)

x <- apistrat

x <- subset( x , comp.imp == 'Yes' )

dstrat_before<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=x, fpc=~fpc)

dstrat_after<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
dstrat_after <- subset( dstrat_after , comp.imp == 'Yes' )


SE( svymean( ~ api00 , dstrat_after ) )
SE( svymean( ~ api00 , dstrat_before ) )
```

Code from: https://gist.github.com/ajdamico/9b3232a1d986b3460baaa90f5fed3402

Comment: 1. Why this happens? 2. Only subsetting or other types of data cleaning too? 3. If answer on question 2 is "some" which one and why?

Comment: @ Anthony Damico, good to see the code. Can you answer the question as to 'why'? @ vasili111, From what I have read of the information for the package, it's because subsetting in your survey object retains information about your overall survey design that you lose if you subset before. I suspect the answer to 2. is 'many', and that to understand which you'll need to read up on how it takes that information into account.