# Is it reasonable to subset a survey design object by dependent (outcome) variable and fit a weighted logistic regression model?

Tags: survey, weighted-regression, survey-sampling, survey-weights

I would like to study which factors are associated with an outcome which has more than two categories. After considering multinomial logistic regression model (which I find is very [challenging](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ejn.16084) to interpret the effect measure "RRR"), I decided to use pairwise binary logistic regression models (weighted), using `survey` package.

However, I am quite concerned if I can subset the survey design object by outcome, because I haven't found people reporting doing this.

Here is an hypothetical example using an existing dataset in `survey` package:

```
library(survey)
data(api)

# a *hypothetical* example
# create a three-level factor variable as outcome variable
apistrat$outcome <- factor(ifelse(
  apistrat$api00 < 600,
  "low",
  ifelse(apistrat$api00 >= 600 &
           apistrat$api00 < 750, "middle", "high") ),
  levels = c("low", "middle", "high") )

summary(apistrat$outcome)

# a stratified random sample
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

model_1 <- svyglm( outcome ~ awards, 
                   design = subset( dstrat, outcome == "low" |
                                      outcome == "middle" ),
        family = quasibinomial( link = "logit" ) )

summary(model_1)

model_2 <- svyglm( outcome ~ awards, 
                   design = subset( dstrat, outcome == "low" |
                                      outcome == "high" ),
                   family = quasibinomial( link = "logit" ) )

summary(model_2)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help! Any comments or thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slightly less efficient way to fit the multinomial model, with the same interpretation as a multinomial model, so it's fine.

Comment: Dear Prof. Lumley, thank you very much for your helpful reply. It is good to know that doing this is reasonable.

About the interpretation of MLR model, from what I read, the effect measure is relative risk ratio (RRR). When studying risk factors for outcome, it becomes quite hard to interpret (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ejn.16084). On the other hand, binary logistic regression model calculates odds ratio (or log-binomial model to calculate risk ratio), which is relatively easier to interpret.

Many thanks again!

Comment: That paper compares multinomial logistic regression to the proportional odds model. Those **are** different.  But multinomial logistic regression **does** estimate the same parameters as logistic regression subsetted down to two groups.

Comment: Many thanks, Prof. Lumley. That is very interesting! I tested this and did find that MLR model estimates the same parameters as logistic regression when subsetted down to two groups. I have added this test results below, in case others are interested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From Prof. Lumley's helpful feedback above, below is to illustrate that MLR model estimates the same parameters as binary logistic regression when subsetted down to two groups:

```
library(survey)
data(api)

# a *hypothetical* example
# create a three-level factor variable as outcome variable
apistrat$outcome <- factor(ifelse(
  apistrat$api00 < 600,
  "low",
  ifelse(apistrat$api00 >= 600 &
           apistrat$api00 < 750, "middle", "high") ),
  levels = c("low", "middle", "high") )

summary(apistrat$outcome)

# a stratified random sample
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)


# fit binary logistic regression model
model_1 <- svyglm( outcome ~ awards, 
                   design = subset( dstrat, outcome == "low" |
                                      outcome == "middle" ),
                   family = quasibinomial( link = "logit" ) )

summary(model_1)

model_2 <- svyglm( outcome ~ awards, 
                   design = subset( dstrat, outcome == "low" |
                                      outcome == "high" ),
                   family = quasibinomial( link = "logit" ) )

summary(model_2)

# fit multinomial logistic regression model
library(svyVGAM)

model_3 <- svy_vglm( outcome ~ awards, 
                     design = dstrat, 
                     family = multinomial( refLevel = "low" )
)

summary(model_3)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]