# Study changes of association between an independent variable and a categorical outcome with more than 2 categories

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multinomial-logit, survey-sampling, survey-weights

Suppose I would like to study the association between sex (male and female; independent variable) and taste preference (sweet, bitter, and sour; dependent variable). I have three cross-sectional surveys(i.e., three datasets), respectively from 2010, 2015, and 2021. These surveys uses complex survey design and survey weights need to be included in the analysis for each year.

**My aims are:**

1. To estimate the strength of association between sex and each taste preference in each year
2. To compare the strength of association across taste preferences
3. To compare the strength of association across years

I can think of three potential approaches to do this:

1. Fit a weighted multinomial logistic regression model, using, for example, sweet as the reference outcome category
2. Subset the data and do pairwise binary logistic regression model, for example, subset the data to include only sweet and bitter, and fit a binary logistic regression model using sweet as the reference
3. Keep the data and fit binary logistic regression, for example, comparing bitter to the rest, comparing sweet to the rest, etc.

**Some thoughts:**
From previous [discussions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629001/is-it-reasonable-to-subset-a-survey-design-object-by-dependent-outcome-variabl), I know that approach 1 and 2 are actually equivalent, which have the same [problems](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ejn.16084) with interpretation of association estimate. Therefore, I want to drop the two options. Approach 3 seems more intuitive and easy to interpret (aim 1 meets).

I would like to ask:

1. Is the above reasoning correct?
2. If yes, can I use approach 3 to compare across taste preferences and years (i.e., aims 2 & 3)? It seems quite hard to be reasonable to compare across taste preferences and across years.

**Any thoughts/comments would be highly appreciated! Thank you! :)**