Removing subjects before creating the survey design object
I have a question regarding the example in this page
https://asdfree.com/national-health-and-nutrition-examination-survey-nhanes.html
I noticed that the author has subsetted the data before creating the survey object in this step
nhanes_df <- subset( nhanes_full_df , ridstatr %in% 2 )

Wouldn't this make the standard errors wrong?

There's a detailed answer to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411026/why-it-is-important-to-make-survey-design-object-svydesign-function-in-r-with-i/414900#414900

so you're absolutely correct that subsetting before the svydesign generally results in incorrect variance estimation.  i believe that you never want to throw out weighted records until after svydesign has been run.
in this nhanes example, however, you're looking at the variable that distinguishes respondents who

answered the survey's questionnaire and also received the entire medical examination, versus
those who only answered the survey's questionnaire

there's actually a different weight for two different groups -- so in this non-standard case it's correct to subset prior to the svydesign()  :-)
thanks and keep in touch
https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2017-2018/DEMO_J.htm
RIDSTATR
WTMEC2YR
WTINT2YR
